# Best way to perform action on 3D Touch on UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

I have a number of `UIButton` instances in a `UIViewController` and I want to perform a couple of actions when any of these buttons are pressed with pressure (all the way down), I don't know the exact term here (force touch maybe?).

So when `UIButton` is pressured, I want to give haptic feedback via vibration, change the button image source and do some other stuff. Then when the pressure is released I want to restore the button image source to the normal state and do some more stuff.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Should I make my own custom `UIButton` like below or are there methods that can be overridden for 3D touch "pressed" and "released".

This is my custom UIButton code so far. Should I determine, by trial and error, what the maximum force should be? Also how do I change the source of the image for each button in the easiest way possible?

```
import AudioToolbox
import UIKit

class customButton : UIButton {
    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            print("% Touch pressure: \(touch.force/touch.maximumPossibleForce)");
            if touch.force > valueThatIMustFindOut {
                AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
                // change image source
                // call external function
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        print("Touches End")
        // restore image source
        // call external function
    }
}
```

Please note that I am new to Swift so I would like to use the graphical interface in Xcode to create the user interface as much as possible. So I would like to avoid creating the UI from the code.

Answer (score 2):

As for the force touch - you need to detect if it's available first:

```
func is3dTouchAvailable(traitCollection: UITraitCollection) -> Bool {
    return traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapability.available
}

if(is3dTouchAvailable(traitCollection: self.view!.traitCollection)) {
   //...
}
```

and then in e.g. touchesMoved it will be available as **touch.force** and **touch.maximumPossibleForce**

```
func touchMoved(touch: UITouch, toPoint pos: CGPoint) {
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    let node = self.atPoint(location)

    //...
    if is3dTouchEnabled {
        bubble.setPressure(pressurePercent: touch.force / touch.maximumPossibleForce)
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here's the more detailed example with code samples:
http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/02/01/swift-how-to-use-3d-touch-introduction/

It's also a good practice to react on such "force touches" with haptic/taptic feedback, so user will experience the touch:

```
let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .heavy)
generator.prepare()

generator.impactOccurred()
```

you might want to take a look at this post for details:
http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/01/29/haptic-feedback-with-uifeedbackgenerator/